# Reemplazar . por , iterando entre Nonetype y valores

Tags: python, excel, scraping

Estoy intentando scrapear multiples paginas para volcar los datos a un excel y calcular algunas cosas. El problema es que en el excel me salta un simbolo de alerta que dice

> "Numero almacenado como texto"

y no me permite hacer cálculos. Normalmente cuando tengo ese problema, reemplazo la coma del decimal por un punto con un `float(item.replace())` y se soluciona pero algunas páginas web están caidas y como no hay datos no me permite hacer el reemplazo. Necesito además mantener en el excel los espacios vacios, para no perder el orden de los datos. Mi codigo es:

```
datos = ["https://www.alot.com.ar/bodbitgrx/p", "https://www.alot.com.ar/clqsybagua-liquido-corrector-sylvapen-berol-base-de-1040-gua-17-ml/p" ]

#Scrapeo los datos y los devuelvo limpios en una lista
precios = []
for i in datos:
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
    browser.get(i)
    #Incorporo BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
    #Extraigo la pagina principal y convierto a str
    pagina_principal_bs4 = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'bestPrice'})
    pagina= str(pagina_principal_bs4)
##    print(pagina)
    pagina = " ".join(pagina.split())
    def cleanhtml(pagina):
        cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
        cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '\n', pagina)
        return cleantext
    texto= cleanhtml(pagina).replace("]","").replace("[","")
    texto = texto.strip()
    precios.append(texto)


#Reemplazo los Nonetype por "  "
precios = np.array(precios)
precios = np.where(precios == "" , "   ", precios)
precios = list(precios)

#Y elimino el signo $ 
precios = [s.replace('$', '') for s in precios]
```

Y aca mi intento que no funciona de reemplazar , por . solo en los items donde hay valores

```
#Reemplazo comas por puntos y los hago float
    precios1 = []
    for i in precios:
        if i == "   ":
            precios1.append(i)
        else:
            float(i.replace(",","."))
            precios1.append(i)
    print(precios1)
```

Me podrían dar una mano?

Comment: ese `if i == "    "` lo puedes cambiar por `if not i.strip()` y luego en el `else` podrías poner un `try/except`, en caso falle el `try` en el `execept` poner `precios1.append("")`